# Error while converting table from spark pool to pandas in synapse notebook

Tags: pandas, azure-synapse

I have a table in the spark pool which i am able to access in synapse. However i am not able to call it as pandas. Below is the error:

```
%%pyspark
rawdata = df.select("*").toPandas()

ArrowInvalid : Casting from timestamp[us, tz=Etc/UTC] to timestamp[ns] would result in out of bounds timestamp: 33460473600000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2132, in toPandas
    pdf = table.to_pandas()
  File "pyarrow/array.pxi", line 715, in pyarrow.lib._PandasConvertible.to_pandas
  File "pyarrow/table.pxi", line 1565, in pyarrow.lib.Table._to_pandas
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py", line 779, in table_to_blockmanager
    blocks = _table_to_blocks(options, table, categories, ext_columns_dtypes)
  File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyarrow/pandas_compat.py", line 1115, in _table_to_blocks
    list(extension_columns.keys()))
  File "pyarrow/table.pxi", line 1028, in pyarrow.lib.table_to_blocks
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 84, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[us, tz=Etc/UTC] to timestamp[ns] would result in out of bounds timestamp: 33460473600000000
```

Comment: Can you please share a bit nmore on what kind of data is there in the table .From the error it looks to me as if some date column is creating issues here .

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue Koalas.